# ScrollView +LinearLayout+GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-scrollview

Добрый день. Проблема такая, надо сделать "длинный" активити. При чем прокручивать только часть экрана, а верхнюю половину оставить неподвижной. 
Во второй части расположил ScrollView +LinearLayout+GridView вот таким образом

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CalendarPager"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/HairGrid"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:scrollIndicators="none"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CalendarPager"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Но беда, почему то GridView сжимается до высоты своей ячейки и начинает скролиться, а надо что бы он был во весь размер, а скролился LinearLayout т.к. под GridView препологается расположение других элементов и еще одного GridView.
Спасибо за внимание! Жду любой помощи!

UPD Надо что бы скролился сам Linerlayout при этом что бы размеры элементов внутри него не менялись и GridView внутри него не начинали скролиться а вытягивались во всю длину своего наполнения(заранее не известного).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте заменить ScrollView на NestedScrollView

Answer (score 1):

Надо понимать, что GridView - это такой специальный хитрый контейнер, который экономит ресурсы. В нем для разных элементов может быть использован один и тот же View, если, например, этот View вышел за пределы видимости при прокрутке, а другой элемент наоборот появился.
Из-за этой особенности `GridView` хорошо подходит для отображения большого количества однообразных элементов, но не так просто заставить его вести себя как, например, LinearLayout и занимать столько места, сколько требуют все элементы вместе взятые.

Для вашего случая существует несколько решений:

1. Правильное

Нужно использовать только один GridView, а все элементы отображать внутри него через разные типы. ViewPager тоже внутри GridView.

Для этого нужно или использовать один адаптер с несколькими типами view или использовать библиотеку вроде https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

2. Костыльное

Нужно вместо GridView использовать другой лайаут и в коде накидать в него контент. Так как вы все равно не планируете пользоваться экономией ресурсов от использования GridView, то вариант сработает.

3. Чуть менее костыльное

Можно попробовать использовать связку RecyclerView + NestedScrollView. Т.е. вместо GridView использовать RecyclerView, а вместо ScrollView - NestedScrollView, как предлагали в комментариях. Это может сработать, но чревато багами.

4. Еще одно костыльное

Искать как заставить GridView раздвигаться под все элементы. Это тоже костыль, по тому как GridView для такого не предназначен и теряется выигрыш производительности как в случае с 2-м вариантом. Я точно где-то уже видел такой костыль, но сходу не нашел.

Update: в последних версиях support library для RecyclerView реализовано растягивание на все необходимое пространство по  wrap_content, но эта фича работает не всегда.

Comment: Как думаете, в офиц. приложении вконтакте какая разметка для профиля используется? Там и ава и статус и все все все а потом стена с постами. Мне кажется это не так делалось. Один адаптер и `itemViewType` - лучший выбор

Comment: Вы правы, разумеется лучше использовать один алаптер. Собственно первым делом я и предлагаю один GridView, а дальше уже костыльные варианты, т.к. отдаленно представляю чего хочет Йорик от нескольких GridView.

Comment: Костыли, костыли :)

Comment: Видимо я плохо изъяснился. Мне надо что бы 2 GridView были разделены ViewPager (размер первого и второго GridView)  я заранее не знаю (данные подгружаю с сервиса). А скролиться надо между этими 3 компонентами.

Comment: Ах да GridView не должны прокручиваться. должны юыть во всю свою длину.

Comment: @Jorik, что значит не должны прокручиваться? Если контент не помещается на экране, то он так или иначе где-то должен прокручиваться. GridView создан для того чтобы прокручиваться. Не понимаю чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: прокручиваться должен слой на котором находится все эти элементы. сами же элементы внутри этого слоя прокручиваться не должны. По сути нужен длинный активити.

Comment: @Jorik, будьте любезны, оформите вопрос. Если получится, то с картинками, по тому как все еще не понятно что за слой должен прокручиваться и как оно по вашему должно выглядеть.

Comment: хорошо. так и сделаю. А то не могу выразить мысли нормально.

Comment: Добавил картинку

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете `RelativeLayout`? Просто у вас в разметке приведет код с расположением вью элементов как с `RelativeLayout`. Попробуйте сделать так:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/HairGrid"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Обратите внимание на длину второго `LinearLayout`, в него вложен `textview`, а под ним уже устанавливайте ваш `ScrollView` и в него поместите `LinearLayout` и в `LinearLayout`помещайте нужные вам вью элементы.

Comment: Все равно сжимает он GridView в высоту ровно одной строчки GridView. А мне надо в этом же LinearLayout еще один GridView добавить и скролиться между ними.